# Why background image not showing in html div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div with a `background-image`, but the image is not showing. If I set the height in pixels (`px`) not percentage(`%`), the image is shown. So, I suspect there is no height set before. But I've set the html body height and width.

The code is below:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="height:100%">
  <div class="leftdisp" style="width:50%;background-image:URL('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491884662610-dfcd28f30cfb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8amFwYW5lc2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8&amp;w=1000&amp;q=80')">

  </div>
  <div class="rightdisp" style="width:50%; background-color:#00000"></div>
</div>
```

I think there's nothing wrong with it? Are there any mistakes I made?

**EDIT:**

I already added `background-size` and `background-repeat`.

Comment: Why you set body with position:absolute? please post also your css

Comment: PS your leftDisp seems doesn't have any height!

Answer (score 2):

Your expectations are wrong. The `height` of `div` (and other block-level elements) is determined by its **content**, unless specified explicitly otherwise.

Since both of your inner `div` elements have no content other than whitespace (a `background-image` is **not** content), their height resolves to `0`.

To fix it, assign a `height` to the `div`s.

Please start using the element inspector in your browser's developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd> on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

first `background-image:url()` second you didnt set height of that image.`

```css
.leftdisp {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="height:100%">
  <div class="leftdisp" style="width:50%;background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491884662610-dfcd28f30cfb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8amFwYW5lc2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8&amp;w=1000&amp;q=80')">

  </div>
  <div class="rightdisp" style="width:50%; background-color:#00000"></div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Please add `min-height` property on `leftdisp` div

Just replace this code

```
 <body>
    <div class="row" style="height:100%">
        <div class="leftdisp" style="width:50%; min-height: 500px; background-image:URL('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491884662610-dfcd28f30cfb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8amFwYW5lc2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8&amp;w=1000&amp;q=80')">
        
        </div>
        <div class="rightdisp" style="width:50%; background-color:#00000"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set image to background, do it in body tag.

```
<body style="width:50%;background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491884662610-dfcd28f30cfb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8amFwYW5lc2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8&amp;w=1000&amp;q=80')">
    <div class="row" style="height:100%">
        <div class="leftdisp">
        
        </div>
        <div class="rightdisp" style="width:50%; background-color:#00000"></div>
    </div>
</body
```